# как перенести из todo в todos ruby on rails

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails

Здравствуйте, не получается перенести из одной таблицы значения в другую через файл `seeds.rb`.
вот его код:

```
data = HashWithIndifferentAccess.new(YAML::load_file(File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds.yml')))

    data[:projects].each do |project|
        p = Project.new(title: project[:title])
        project[:todos].each do |todo|
            p.todos << Todo.create(todo)
        end
        p.save!
    end
```

файл `todo.rb`:

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :project
end
```

файл `project.rb`:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos
 end
```

файл `index.html.rb`:

```
<h1>Задачи</h1>
<table>
  <% @project.each do |project| %>
    <tr>
      <tr><td><%= project.title %></td></tr>
      <tr><td><%= project.todos %></td></tr>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
</table>
```

короче говоря `project.todos` пустой и выводятся иероглифы, что я делаю не так? спасибо

Comment: 1) попробуйте создавать 'todos' через 'p.todos.create(todo)' (чет я не уверен что сработает '.create(todo)' сработает, т.к. не указаны поля, но могу ошибаться). 2) в HTML todos следует выводить так же через 'each'. 3)

Comment: Да и перед тем как создавать вложенную модель надо сохранить 'p